# Suggest edits without actually making them

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edits

At 2000 reputation, users are given the ability to *"edit anything in the system without it going through the peer review system"*, which is undoubtedly useful when it comes to correcting poor grammar and making a question more intelligible in general.

However, I often find myself *thinking* I know what a question means without actually being sure, and consequently I am reluctant to make an edit clarifying said question, as I don't want to change what it is really asking. For this reason, it may prove useful to have a mechanism through which 2000+ reputation users can still *suggest* edits to an OP without actually making them.

Comment: "suggested edits" are not so much suggested to the OP, but to the community at large.

Comment: How about guiding the OP towards your suggested edits by adding comment(s)?

Comment: I'm agree with @AzizShaikh. I usually comments for editing or clarifying the question, If I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comment and ask for clarification from the OP.

Suggested edits are there for *others* to look at and approve/deny (though the OP will also get notified). It is not a mechanism to suggest changes to the OP.